# Android WebView embedded (flash) video player

Tags: php, android, html, flash, webview

**Situation**

In my application I have a `WebView` which loads its data inside an IFrame from an url.

Code Snippet:

```
String url = www.myexampleurl.com/video1.html;
String data = "<IFRAME SRC=" + url + " FRAMEBORDER=0 ... />";
WebView.loadData(data, MIME_TYPE, ENCODING);
```

The website itself, loads his video into a flash player and I simply display this in the `WebView`. This works perfectly, with one nasty sidenote... Android has stopped supporting flash which means in the future my application will not work anymore by default. -Not acceptable!-

**What I tried already**

*Solution to replace the flashplayer*

I fetched the url of the video that is given to the flashplayer and I load it directly inside a `VideoView` or `WebView` with HTML5. These work solutions work! Perfect! But again a nasty sidenote.

The url (ex. www.myexampleurl.com/video1/video.mp4) is being generically created by the website (I think for each session). This means I don't have a consistent path to the video to load in my `View`. The advantage of my first approach with the flashplayer inside the `Webview` was that the flashplayer does all the work.

*Solution to get the correct video-url*

No serious problem yet, because I can tackle this problem too. I can do some PHP/DOM-scripting which would scrape the website for the video-url and give it back to my application. This way I always have the generic url and my video can be loaded inside my `View`. Again that works! And again.. there is a sidenote..

I can not go directly to my website that has the flashplayer. The flow can be as followed:

1. Enter www.myexampleurl.com/video1.html
2. Get the message: Wait 5 seconds
3. Click continue
4. Video is starting to play inside the flashplayer.

The problem is that I get my video url only after step 3.

**Question**

Is there a way to solve my getting-the-generic-url problem? Or a better approach to play the video?

-- Is it bad, very bad or extremely bad practice to continue to support flash in Android? I can also just provide the flashplayer .apk and let users install it..

Thanks, hope someone can help me :)!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do drugs. Don't do flash.

Get the file up on a server you have control of so you can give a proper path. If that is not an option, you'll have an app that can brake any moment the owner of the website decides to change something with the path.

Comment: Hosting my files is not an option. That the owner can change his or remove his file, is an accepted scenario. My main block is the 5 second wait that the website needs to verify your session or something. After that, the correct page is loaded and regardless if the video is renamed or moved.. I can get the correct path because it will be linked to the flashplayer anyway

Comment: But why do you have the delay? Verification takes time or?

Comment: An example with similar behavior would be this: http://gorillavid.in/yyrxcrapfy5r

Answer (score 0):

Is parsing www.myexampleurl.com/video1.html the only way to fecth the url you want?
Maybe you can do the PHP/dom stuff in the client instead of in your server: use an invisible `WebView` to load www.myexampleurl.com/video1.html and try to get the url from it.
`WebViewClient::onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)` may be helpful (I am not sure). This task must be achievable by hacking `WebView`, the problem is how complicated it will be.

Comment: That is one of the solutions I am considering. This would mean opening the website, waiting untill the scripts ran, simulate the click on Continue and then fetch the html and find the video-url I need. Complicated, it will be ;). Thanks for you input.